# Is it possible to highlight text with the keyboard only?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, highlighting

I know you can highlight text with the mouse, but can this be done in a terminal on Linux/MacOSX with the keyboard only? I've tried using <kbd>shift</kbd> and other commands with the arrow keys to no avail.

Is this not possible with the keyboard?

Comment: Linux? Windows?

Comment: I don't think it matters.  neither native terminals will support keyboard control for highlighting.

Comment: Linux/MacOSX terminal

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using tmux. You can set it up with your own keyboard to highlight and copy text. See [here](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2011/06/07/copy-and-paste-in-tmux/).

Answer (score 0):

To highlight the text in the linux ,you can use the below command

shift+arrow - highlight text

shift+ctrl+arrow - highlight an entire word

Please update us if you have issues.

Comment: This doesn't work in the MacOSX terminal or my virtual machine Ubuntu 14.04 terminal. MacOSX: Pressing Shift + left comes up as `;2D` and shift + right arrow `;2C` instead of highlighting text. Linux: comes up as `D` and `C` when pressing shift left/right.